# Running several .bat files within command prompt

Tags: batch-file, wso2, command-prompt

I am trying to start the wso2 iot server with the command prompt, to do that i have to execute three .bat files which have the same name and are in different folders, is it possible to start them all in the same command prompt ? and if not how can i execute them in an alternative way ?  thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the absolute filename of each. OR you could change directory to each and run the batch name.

pushd/popd changes to the directory and back if you don't want to `cd`.

Remeber to "quote the fullpathtobatchname" if it contains spaces. If you are using `start` then remember to include a windowtitle as the first quoted parameter if using quoted arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, only need chance the `offset`value in your `[ESB_HOME]\repository\conf\carbon.xml`to 2 servers so that they are not exposed by the same port. regards

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem, when i try to run the second bat I get a pile of errors, and i can no longer access carbon home through the web browser

```
C:\wso2\wso2esb-5.0.0\tmp\AXIS2-~1.TMP\axis22597661185720064274rampart-1.6.1-wso2v18.mar - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\wso2\wso2esb-5.0.0\tmp\AXIS2-~1.TMP\axis2545956122453586080addressing-1.6.1-wso2v19.mar - The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
C:\wso2\wso2esb-5.0.0\tmp\javasysmon64130642671302902180.dll - Access is denied.
C:\wso2\wso2esb-5.0.0\tmp\javasysmon65576392292672845032.dll - Access is denied.
```